# Contact is missing some of the required key descriptors in ios

Tags: ios, ios9, contacts

I have retrieves all contact by using following method

```
- (void)getAllContacts:(void(^)(NSArray *array))handler
{
    CNAuthorizationStatus status = [CNContactStore authorizationStatusForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts];

    if (status == CNAuthorizationStatusDenied || status == CNAuthorizationStatusDenied)
    {
        UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:@"This app previously was refused permissions to contacts; Please go to settings and grant permission to this app so it can use contacts" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        [alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil]];
        [self presentViewController:alert animated:TRUE completion:nil];
        return;
    }

    CNContactStore *store = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];
    [store requestAccessForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {

        // make sure the user granted us access
        if (!granted)
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                // user didn't grant access;
                // so, again, tell user here why app needs permissions in order  to do it's job;
                // this is dispatched to the main queue because this request could be running on background thread
            });
            return;
        }

        // build array of contacts
        NSMutableArray *contacts = [NSMutableArray array];

        NSError *fetchError;
        CNContactFetchRequest *request = [[CNContactFetchRequest alloc] initWithKeysToFetch:@[CNContactIdentifierKey, CNContactEmailAddressesKey, CNContactBirthdayKey, CNContactImageDataKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, [CNContactFormatter descriptorForRequiredKeysForStyle:CNContactFormatterStyleFullName]]];

        BOOL success = [store enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest:request error:&fetchError usingBlock:^(CNContact *contact, BOOL *stop) {

            [contacts addObject:contact];
        }];

        if (!success)
        {
            NSLog(@"error = %@", fetchError);
            return;
        }
        handler((NSArray *)contacts);
   }];
```

}

And contacts are listed in tableview. Now I am trying to select particular contact from ``,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CNContact *contact = [arrContacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSArray *keys = @[CNContactIdentifierKey, CNContactEmailAddressesKey, CNContactBirthdayKey, CNContactImageDataKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, [CNContactFormatter descriptorForRequiredKeysForStyle:CNContactFormatterStyleFullName]];
    CNContactViewController *contactController = [CNContactViewController viewControllerForContact:contact];
    contactController.delegate = self;
    contactController.allowsEditing = YES;
    contactController.allowsActions = YES;
    contactController.displayedPropertyKeys = keys;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:contactController animated:TRUE];
}
```

But it says

> Contact 0x7fc732654530 is missing some of the required key descriptors

Please help me to solve it, if anyone know. Thanks.

Comment: Here is the link for address book demo. I hope this link helps you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17976915/3378413

Comment: Thanks... @MihirOza, But now `AddressBook.framework` is deprecated. So now I want to use `Contacts.framework`.

Comment: @MihirOza There is nothing to get useful in this link. It is totally blank demo app like developed by newbie.

Comment: I have the same error. My guess is that the fetched keys array is not complete (a key is missing)

Comment: I have tried all the way, but still not get solution, Please up vote the question, so someone can give answer who know about it.

Comment: i am also getting same issue please post answer whenever you find it

Comment: @Zika M solution is work perfect

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Add "CNContactViewController.descriptorForRequiredKeys" at the end of your keysToFetch array.

Worked for me after I did that.

Example:

```
NSArray *keysToFetch = @[CNContactIdentifierKey, CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactImageDataAvailableKey, CNContactImageDataKey, CNContactViewController.descriptorForRequiredKeys];
```

Comment: In Swift: `let keysToFetch: [CNKeyDescriptor] = [CNContactIdentifierKey, CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactImageDataAvailableKey, CNContactImageDataKey, CNContactViewController.descriptorForRequiredKeys()]`

Answer (score 4):

Change you line

```
 CNContactFetchRequest *request = [[CNContactFetchRequest alloc] initWithKeysToFetch:@[CNContactIdentifierKey, CNContactEmailAddressesKey, CNContactBirthdayKey, CNContactImageDataKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, [CNContactFormatter descriptorForRequiredKeysForStyle:CNContactFormatterStyleFullName]]];
```

with

```
 CNContactFetchRequest *request = [[CNContactFetchRequest alloc] initWithKeysToFetch:@[CNContactIdentifierKey, CNContactEmailAddressesKey, CNContactBirthdayKey, CNContactImageDataKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, [CNContactFormatter descriptorForRequiredKeysForStyle:CNContactFormatterStyleFullName],[CNContactViewController descriptorForRequiredKeys]]];
```

and some one use it in swift then add like

```
let request:CNContactFetchRequest
request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactMiddleNameKey, CNContactEmailAddressesKey,CNContactPhoneNumbersKey,CNContactViewController.descriptorForRequiredKeys()])
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `[CNContactViewController descriptorForRequiredKeys]` as an array of `keysToFetch` you have to pass in your `CNContactFetchRequest`.

Example:

```
CNContactFetchRequest *request = [[CNContactFetchRequest alloc] initWithKeysToFetch:@[CNContactIdentifierKey, CNContactEmailAddressesKey, CNContactBirthdayKey, CNContactImageDataKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, [CNContactFormatter descriptorForRequiredKeysForStyle:CNContactFormatterStyleFullName], [CNContactViewController descriptorForRequiredKeys]]];
```

Comment: Where? You missed `[CNContactViewController ForRequiredKeys]`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is a bug with Apple's error handling or my lack of understanding, but my solution had absolutely nothing to do with the key descriptors.

In the case of trying to display a `CNContact` in a `CNContactViewController` picked from a `CNContactPickerViewController` *without* contact permissions, you must make sure the `CNContactViewController` is embedded inside a `UINavigationController`.

In my case I also had to add left and right `UIBarButtonItem`'s to the controller to handle dismissal. Note this might not be necessary if you are pushing the `CNContactViewController` onto a `UINavigationController`, however as I was using the `present` method, it was necessary.

Hope this will help someone else solve this cryptic error!