# How to fetch Birthday Label from CNContactPickerViewController in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cncontact, cncontactviewcontroller

I know in swift how to pick Birthday Label from CNContactPickerViewController, but i am little bit confuse in Objective-c

Here i use code like:In Objective-c

How can i pick Birthday label in "didSelectContactProperty" method. Can you please help me out..

```
-(void)presentContacts {
    CNContactPickerViewController *picker = [[CNContactPickerViewController alloc] init];
    NSArray *propertyKeys = @[CNContactBirthdayKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactOrganizationNameKey];
    NSPredicate *enablePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"birthday != nil"];

    picker.displayedPropertyKeys = propertyKeys;
    picker.predicateForEnablingContact = enablePredicate;
    picker.delegate = self;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)contactPickerDidCancel: (CNContactPickerViewController *) picker {
    NSLog(@"didCancel");
}

- (void)contactPicker: (CNContactPickerViewController *) picker didSelectContact: (CNContact *)contact{    
    NSLog(@"didSelectContact");
}

- (void)contactPicker: (CNContactPickerViewController *) picker didSelectContactProperty: (CNContactProperty *)contactProperty{
     NSLog(@"didSelectProperty");
}
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975297/retrieve-all-contacts-phone-numbers-in-ios

Comment: currently i am using XCode 7.3, i need to get solution for this question using Contact Framework and 
ContactUI Framework these frameworks

Comment: And more over i want to pick specific contact from "CNContactPickerViewController" only. I don't want to show all contacts birthdays list at a time...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32669612/how-to-fetch-all-contacts-record-in-ios-9-using-contacts-framework check @Eridana answer

Comment: Hi @@Eridana, I clearly mentioned "How to Pick Birthday Label from CNContactPickerViewController in objective-c?" .. I already know how to get all contacts list(fname, lname, profilepic, emailid and etc..)

Comment: - (void)contactPicker: (CNContactPickerViewController *) picker
      didSelectContact: (CNContact *)contact{
    NSLog(@"didSelectContact");
}  -----> here i need to write some code to get Birth day label. How can i get?

Comment: `CNContact` has a `birthday` property.