# Import Contact List in Mobile App XCode

Tags: android, ios, xcode, contacts

I am creating an app in xcode and I would like to be able to access people's contact list from their phone on the app. Is their a tutorial/library that can guide me in this?

Comment: You are creating android app or for iOS?

Comment: If this can be done across platforms It would be better it is IOS

Comment: You are using multi OS engine?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34193534/5725512 for iOS please refer this answer

Comment: I will focus on IOS for right now.

Comment: @Pushp this seems to be the right step. Thank you.

Comment: @DapperArtisan wel come