# Does any one know how to implement to display the list of contacts from phone book from search bar in a tableview cell?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, tableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

How to achieve the UI attached in a screenshot? . I have a tableview and multi custom cells inside it.From One custom cell, while searching the name or phone number i want to display the contacts retrieved from Addressbook in that tableview itself as new view or a tableview.I dont want to navigate to address book or navigate to custom search controller. Does any one know how to implement this?
Like the screenshot attached.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vqal7.png)

Comment: Is that you using Contact framework or AddessBook?

Comment: Have a look to  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975297/retrieve-all-contacts-phone-numbers-in-ios

Comment: Yes it is using Contacts framework @Jaydeep

Comment: @Vikky i am not asking how to access..I want to achieve that kind of UI,how to achieve that?

Comment: OK got your point, you can use tableView to show the search result when clicked on textfield.You should elaborate more what is your actual requirement

Comment: @Vikky I am new to iOS,so i am looking for how to sub class the tableview to tableview cell and display the tableview when user clicked on the text field to show the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented some time ago this kind of textview and solved my problem.

I think you should implement **`ZTDropDownTextField`** this is third party class, Please check below link

Note : This is only for UI like your screenshot

[ZTDropDownTextField](https://github.com/ziyang0621/ZTDropDownTextField)

Comment: Thanks Vivek..It helps!!

Comment: Can you please accept my answer, it is helpful to me

Comment: I am not sure how to accept your answer,but the solution would have been nice if that dropdown textfield is from tableview instead of a view.

Comment: There's a 'check' thing (like a v) next to the answers which you can click on. When it turns green it means you accepted that answer. Hope that helps :)  please check also below.link for your reference https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow